# How to optimize pyspark join with fill last occurance?

Tags: join, pyspark

I have two dataframes: stage_changes, journeys with their description as follows,

In my app, every candidate gets associated with a level_id on his starting day. Candidate's level is changed whenever some progress is made, so duration of num of days between level change is not fixed.

For example, candiate-A is on level-0 on day-0 then level-1 on day-5 then directly level-4 on day-25. This data is tracked in the dataframe stage_changes.

```
stage_changes:

account_id | candidate_id | day_num | level_id
    21     |     23097    |    0    |    0
    21     |     23097    |    5    |    1
    21     |     23097    |    25   |    4
    45     |     53838    |    4    |    0
    45     |     23097    |    30   |    7
    21     |     23056    |    45   |    1
```

Every candidate is active for a specific period, described as starting_day to ending_day. And this is tracked in another dataframe journeys as,

```
journeys:

account_id | candidate_id | starting_day | ending_day
    21     |     23097    |    0         |    76
    45     |     53838    |    4         |    45
    21     |     23056    |    45        |    101
```

I want to get level_id of every candidate on each day during his/her journey. I am currently doing this as follows,

```
@udf("array<integer>")
def day_range(start_day, end_day):
    return list(range(start_day, end_day+1))


all_journey_days = journeys \
        .withColumn("day_range", day_range(col("starting_day"), col("ending_day"))) \
        .select(["account_id", "candidate_id", explode("day_range").alias("day_num")])

window = Window().partitionBy(["account_id", "candidate_id"]).orderBy("day_num") \
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

all_day_stage_changes = all_journey_days \
        .join(stage_changes, on=["account_id", "candidate_id", "day_num"], how="left") \
        .withColumn("final_level_id", last(col("level_id"), ignorenulls=True).over(window))
```

I'm getting the correct output as per this code, but this takes several minutes considering huge data size at my end. Is there any optimization to this, so that the whole process can finish quickly?

```
Important points:
1. Every candidate has different activity period.
2. Level changes of every candidate are different, there is no hidden logic here.
3. The number of candidates is ~1M and their avg. activity period ~100 days.
4. Every pair of account_id, candidate_id is unique in the system and not only the candidate_id.
```

Comment: What’s your spark version? Is any of the join dataframes smaller than 8gigs?

Comment: spark2.2 and no, the data is more than 8GB.